# counting forward work out how long time a is after time b

Tags: python, datetime

I need a way to find out how long one datetime.time is after another datetime.time  Quite simple, but... the problem is that my time values are in 24 hour time so it's not as simple as negating one value from another. Instead i need to work out how long time_b is after time_a if I were to count forward in time and at midnight time loops round, i.e.

```
time_a = 09:00
time_b = 04:00
```

Here time_b is 19 hours after time_a

```
def time_after_time(time_a, time_b):

    a_hour = time_a.hour
    a_minute = time_a.minute
    b_hour = time_b.hour
    b_minute = time_b.minute

    out_hour = b_hour - a_hour
    out_minute = b_minute - a_minute

    if out_hour < 0:
        out_hour += 24

    if out_minute < 0:
        out_hour -= 1
        out_minute += 60

    return datetime.time(out_hour, out_minute)
```

This was my first try but its giving false results.

Can anyone think of a cleaner/correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not use `datetime.timedelta`? `time_b - time_a` will produce a `timedelta`.

Comment: this works for datetime.datetime objects but not datetime.time objects unfortunatley

Comment: @MartijnPieters it looks like the assumption is the time is for the same date... So, not quite sure what answer is expected...

Comment: is 09:00 - 10:00 = 1 hour or is it 25 hours? is the max 24 hours then?

Comment: so if `a` = 09:00 and `b` = 10:00 then `b` is 1 hour after `a` but `a` is 23 hours after `b`, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
def time_after_time(time_a, time_b):
    time_a_min = time_a.hour * 60 + time_a.minute
    time_b_min = time_b.hour * 60 + time_b.minute
    out_min = time_b_min - time_a_min
    if out_min < 0:
        out_min += 24 * 60
    return datetime.time(out_min / 60, out_min % 60)
```

You can test it on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/QMXWjZXR).

Answer (score 0):

```
timedif = DATETIME_1 - DATETIME_2
print timedif
```

make sure you use datetime.datetime times ...

you can convert datetime.time to datetime with

```
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.now().date(),datetimeTime_obj)
```

is 09:00 - 10:00 = 1 hour or is it 25 hours? is the max 24 hours then?

```
import datetime

time_a = datetime.time(9,00)
time_b = datetime.time(5,0)
dte = datetime.datetime.now().date()

dt_a = datetime.datetime.combine(dte,time_a)

dt_b = datetime.datetime.combine(dte,time_b)
time_dif = dt_b - dt_a
time_dif2 = dt_a - dt_b
print "TimeDif:",time_dif,time_dif2
#output: 20:00:00 , 04:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is *essential* that whenever you receive a 24-hour-based time-stamp from an external source, you should immediately convert it internally to an absolute time, such as seconds from 1970. See, for example in `C`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859648/318716  for a way to do this.

Once you *do* this, then simple subtraction of times becomes easy and valid.

If you *don't* do this, then problems with timestamps ***differing by 48 hours*** will eventually arise.

Such a conversion *sometimes* should not be based on the current date/time if, for example, you were doing an analysis of historical archived data, or a playback.

Comment: his time differences should never be more than 23:59 hours ... according to his problem statement

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Maybe I'm blind, but I can't see this in the problem statement. And if it were so, then this wouldn't be a real-world problem. But, ***unfortunately***, I've also seen many incorrect 'real-world' solutions. And this has no impact on my suggested solution.

Comment: the times should indeed never be more that 23.59 appart but it it true that I didn't explicitly state this

Answer (score 0):

***Second answer*** (which I don't advise, for reasons given in my first answer). In `C` you could have:

```
int time1MinusTime2Positive(int t1, int t2) { // returns dt from 0 to <24 hours
    return fmod(t1 - t2 + 100 * 24 * 60 * 60, 24 * 60 * 60);
}

int time1MinusTime2(int t1, int t2) { // returns dt between -12 and +12 hours
    const int dt = t1 - t2;
    if (dt > 24 * 60 * 60 / 2)
       return dt - 24 * 60 * 60;
    else if (dt < -24 * 60 * 60 / 2)
       return dt + 24 * 60 * 60;
    else
       return dt;
}
```

Here the input times are expressed as seconds from midnight, or seconds from 1970, or from 1900--it doesn't matter. Outputs are in seconds, relative to the 'current' midnight, whatever 'current' might mean.